# How to add some bytes quantity?

Tags: string-manipulation, units

I have some **strings** like:

```
st={"29M", "53K", "27K", "5.0M", "29M", "4.0K", "4.0M", "114M", "20K", "1.3G"}
```

They are some bytes quantity, could we **add** or **sort** them all with a simple method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, so first we convert them into quantities:

```
quantities = Interpreter[Restricted["Quantity", "Megabytes"]][st]
```

Now we can eg add them with `Total@quantities` or sort them with `Sort@quantities`.

In the `Interpreter` specification, we restrict the type of quantity to one that is compatible with `"Megabytes"`. This is because otherwise, "4.0K" is normally interpreted as 4 Kelvin, "1.3G" is interpreted as 1.3 times the gravitational constant, etc. If you want your units to be raw bytes, or some other storage units, you can change the second argument to `Restricted`.

Comment: That's very strange - I get nothing like that and the output is virtually immediate. This might be an issue with your local Mathematica or even just the notebook you currently have runnng. Anyway, glad to help.

Comment: Good solution..

Comment: After I restart the kernel, that strange disappear :)

Comment:  Great stuff!

Comment: As your answer and [this response](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/170843/21532), `Interpreter[Restricted["Quantity", "MiB"]] /@ st` is more appropriate here.

Comment: Aha, that's one of those things that I always forget! Thanks, I'll remember that in future!